# Find location on image use as an map

Tags: ios

I have to find my location on image . 
http://www.mallorcaresidencia.com/layout/map_230_0.png

touch on North area , tap on center,tap on south etc. find location particular area then event generate.

```
if (((touchLocation.x <219 && touchLocation.y>19) && (touchLocation.x <221 && touchLocation.y<97))  || ((touchLocation.x <143 && touchLocation.y<78)  && (touchLocation.x >129 && touchLocation.y<58))) {
            cellimgmap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_north.png"];
        }else if (((touchLocation.x >218 && touchLocation.y<94) && (touchLocation.x <270 && touchLocation.y>165))  || ((touchLocation.x <298 && touchLocation.y>111)  && (touchLocation.x >257 && touchLocation.y>84))) {
            cellimgmap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_northeast.png"];
        }else if (((touchLocation.x >131 && touchLocation.y>55) && (touchLocation.x <135 && touchLocation.y<111))  || (touchLocation.x <102 && touchLocation.y<135)  || ((touchLocation.x <69 && touchLocation.y<150)  && (touchLocation.x >42 && touchLocation.y<133))) {
            cellimgmap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_westnorthwest.png"];
        }
```

Comment: How you can find your location ? Using MapView or just image Location ?

Comment: Really, I can't understand well what you mean. However, I think you have to create *n* `UIButton` for each *region* in the image. Then you have to catch the **Touch Up Inside** event on `UIButton`

Comment: I have to use tap gesture on image view. and tap point on particular location . example working same in http://www.mallorcaresidencia.com/ use map image

Comment: What should happen if somebody taps e.g. on the "north area"? And what card region is showed initially? Can you show some of your code so people can understand better what your intentions are?